# Sunken back patio drains water towards basement wall. Any quick fixes to reduce loading on wall from ice?

Tags: concrete, basement, foundation, sealing

My concrete back patio has sunken into the ground over the years. Eventually I want to have it jacked with foam to bring it back to a good level but I need to get through the winter as is. The way it sunk causes water to drain towards the house and water seaps through the ground right next to my basement wall. Should I put rubber sealer between the basement wall and the slab to prevent water from saturating the soil next to the wall? I have some small cracks already developing in the wall that indicate that side loading from ice has happened in the past. There's actually a lot of cracks throughout the basement but I'm working my way through them with structural epoxy from Simpson.

I guess my options are:

1. Fill the gap with sealer so water forms puddles on top of the slab
2. Same as 1 but water tight concrete filler (not flexible)
3. Let the water drain through the slot anyway
4. I have to fix the slab. This is really bad
5. Something else?

What do you think I should do?

Thanks y'all! FYI I live in Colorado so it snows and freezes a lot here in the winter.

[image: Patio]

[image: Patio2]

Comment: That vertical wall of concrete at the right, is that a stairwell? Does it have a drain at the bottom?

Comment: If there's a low spot nearby, you could cut the slab parallel to the foundation. 8" away maybe. Bury a drainage line parallel to the foundation in clean 3/4" gravel. There has to be a path with downward slope to a low spot, although a pump can work. Pumping during a Colorado winter sounds complicated.

Comment: The "low spot" can be a dry well, which disperses the water into the soil at a reasonable distance from the house.

Comment: @keshlam, how does the frost line interact with that sort of thing? I would be afraid of the surrounding ground icing over, turning the well into a reservoir until Spring. Does it need a bit of heat supplied to keep it thawed?

Comment: Websearch dry well for specs... Odds of it freezing solid would seem pretty low, presuming water drains from it into the surrounding ground.

Comment: Don't know where in CO the OP is @popham, but generally one has to dig a well pretty deep to find water in the mountains. A dry well seems to be a pretty good idea. Maybe you or keshlam could turn these into an answer.

Comment: @FreeMan, I thought to myself, "Rocky Mountains? There's no way there's clay." Begrudgingly I looked it up, and I guess they have clay all over the place. I'm still skeptical. It sounds ridiculous. Expansive soil, though, fits with the foundation cracks. Clay soil would probably turn the dry well idea into an expensive one. I did a bit of research, though, and will write up the dry well idea. If not for the OP, then at least for others with the same question.

Comment: What kind of soil do you have @Cnicho35?

Comment: @popham The wall on the right is a stair that goes up to the back door. From what I can tell, the house has no draining system. No sump pump or french drains, unfortunately. When I installed my radon system, I was under the slab and just saw the concrete wall footer. Basement wall is a slab - not cinderblocks fyi.

Comment: @popham - I'm unsure what kind of soil is around my house. I will do a bit of research and get back to you

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I was hoping to avoid any major concrete surgery because I will eventually have the patio lifted/replaced/removed and would prefer to save my money for that. Does anyone have thoughts about just sealing the seam between the patio and the basement wall? Besides being a slip hazard, do you see any problem with that approach?

Comment: Rather than lift it, a contractor will probably advise you to top it with another slab. If you make a pond of it, then there's a high likelihood that the water bleeds through your foundation into the basement.

Comment: Do you have enough fall on the slab to be able to cut a drainage gutter in it to drain from the low spot to the edge of the slab?